# What is the s3 permission to allow the user the rights to enable the bucket for static website hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the s3 permission to allow the user the rights to enable the bucket for static website hosting? We don't want to give the user all the s3 permissions, we only give him the necessary permissions. Together with some read and write permissions, what is the permission for enable bucket for static website hosting?

Comment: Do you have a starting bucket and bucket policy? What permissions are you trying to avoid giving out here?

Comment: i have a bucket but don't have a bucket policy yet. The basic permissions I want give the user are PutObject, GetObject, DeleteObject and ListBucket plus the permission to allow the user to enable static website hosting, which I don't know what are they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by adding 'PutBucketWebsite' to your policy.